# How do I find the equation of the corresponding circle?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Let $C$ be a circle whose center belongs to first quadrant. Circle $C$ is tangent to lines $y + 3 = 0$ and $4y - 3x - 12 = 0$. Given information what is the equation for circle $C$.

My Attempt:

I found that center coordinates $O(x_1 , y_1)$ has relation $3y_1 = x_1 - 1$ and $r=| y_1 + 3| = ( |4y_1 - 3x_1 -12| ) /5$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where have you gotten stuck? What kind of class is this for?

Comment: I found that center coordinates O(x1 , y1)  has relation 3y1 = x1 - 1 and r=| y1 + 3| =  ( |4y1 - 3x1 -12| ) /5

Comment: This is class 12 geometry in my country but ım class 10 and studying for fun (also for olympic math)

Comment: If you need help formatting any mathematics see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it will make your posts and comments much more readable.

Comment: And tysm for editing since ım on phone its so hard to write anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are infinitely many circles can be drawn touching these two lines.

The characteristics of these circle are having their centers lying on the angle bisector between these two lines.

The equation of that angle bisector can by found either by formula; or

the following hard way:-

-(1) find the point of intersection of these two lines;

-(2) find the angle between these two lines;

-(3) use half the angle found in (2) to get the slope;

-(4) use point-slope form to build the equation of that angle bisector.

That angle bisector happens to be -x +3y = -1.

Next, we have to find where the line will cut the x-axis. [Answer (1, 0)].

Conclusion: There are infinitely many circles can be drawn touching these two lines. The centers of these circles ly on the line ... and the smallest one is centered at .... with radius  = ...

Answer (score 1):

You can assume the equation of a circle
$$
(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = r^2
$$
and try to determine the three unknowns $(x_0, y_0)$ and $r$ from the other information.

Comment: This is so emberassing but ı misread the problem it says point O is in x axis  with knowing that equation is (x-1)^2  + y^2 = 9. But without that info its a very interesting problem

Comment: Without that info you have a whole family of solutions, so you definitely needed something else to find a unique circle.

Comment: You can think what does it mean for a line to be tangent to a circle. This should yield more equations and maybe enough to solve.

Comment: @BilalErgüç if this answer your question you can accept it by clicking on the grey button to make it green showing you accept this answer